# My Material UI button is not showing up and making nothing show up in my web app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use Material UI to use buttons in my web app using ReactJS for the frontend. I installed Material UI with the terminal command

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

And my code looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="headerRight">
        <h1>Hi There</h1>
        <img
          className="headerIcon"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Bill_Gates_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
        <div className="button">
          <Button>Click Me</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

and the compiler says "Compiled Successfully!" when I hit save, but when I look at the app in my browser, nothing is there at all. When I take out the button, everything else shows up, but when I put the button back in, nothing shows up, and I get a blank screen. I'm really frustrated trying to figure out why the Material UI button does not work. Please help me.

My **App.js** code looks like this

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Banner from './Banner';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Banner/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: <div >
hiiii
    </div>

Comment: please put it in your app component and tell me what happens?

Comment: If I put it in the app component, adding the button makes nothing show up.

Comment: and did you check the console ? are there any errors there ?

Comment: @CaptainApollo Make sure if you closed `h1` tag, I edited to close.

Answer (score 0):

Issue for me was that I had installed MUI before jumping into my react ap (cd my-app), so the MUI package was in a parent "Node Modules" directory of my react app.

Deleted the parent Node Modules directory and reinstalled MUI in my react app.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar scenario, while migrating from material/core (mui 4) -> @mui/material (mui 5),

Followed the first solution provided, it did not work, however, on deleting the node_modules of my project and cleaning my npm cache with

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Worked for me.